# Python2 : Create a list of dictionaries from two list of values

Tags: python-2.7

I have two input lists as following:

```
x_values = [1,2,3]   
y_values = [1,2,3]
```

Is there a quick way to create a list of dictionaries from these two lists, like following:

```
points = [{x=1, y=1},{x=2, y=2},{x=3, y=3}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question this should help:

```
>>> x_values = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y_values = [1, 2, 3]
>>> points = [{"x":i, "y":j} for i, j in zip(x_values, y_values)]
>>> points
[{'y': 1, 'x': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2}, {'y': 3, 'x': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a more Pythonic way to do this, but one straight forward approach could be:

```
x_values = [1,2,3]   
y_values = [1,2,3]
points = []

i = 0
while i < len(x_values):
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict['y'] = y_values[i]
    new_dict['x'] = x_values[i]
    points.append(new_dict)
    i += 1
```

This may at least get you going.